# Скрытие курсора при наведении на определенный контрол

Tags: wpf, c#

Подскажите, как скрыть курсор (сделать невидимым) при наведении на определенный контрол и показать снова после того, как нужный контрол покинут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в событие `MouseEnter` для контрола установить: `Cursor.Hide()`,
а в `MouseLeave` - `Cursor.Show()`

Answer (score 3):

Установить пустой курсор для этого контрола.